# How to configure Permissions: SQLite for ASP.Net Website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sqlite, permissions

I am trying to use SQLite for my ASP.Net Website.
The code is working fine in a Windows Application, but not in the WebAPP. I think I have to change some File Permissions to let the Website set up a Database. But how?

I always get a ERROR at the `open()` statement. Saying `cannot open file`.

Following the Code, which is working fine in the WindowsAPP:

```
Dim connDB as SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("PlayerDB.sqlite")
Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=PlayerDB.sqlite;Version=3")
conn.open()   ---> ERROR
...
```

I hope someone can help me quick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why you can get this error, so you must make sure that both these are taken care of before running your code.

- `You need to specify the absolute path to the database in your connection string and not a relative path that you are currently using in your code` since SQLite database is just a file. For this you need to create a special folder for sqlite databases in your ASP.Net app. Let's say you have created a folder called `sqlite` under the root folder. Then your code should be as below. `Server.MapPath` is an utility method in ASP.Net framework to convert a root relative path to an absolute path that looks like `c:\abc\wwq\myfile.db`.

  ```
  Dim connDB as SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data
          Source={0};Version=3;",Server.MapPath("~/sqlite/PlayerDB.sqlite"))); 

  conn.open()   ---> NO ERROR should happen now
  ```
- `You should also make sure that the ASP.Net application identity is allowed read/write access to the`sqlite`folder created in above step` under the root of your web app because data will be read as well as written to the database file under this folder.

  Just right click on the `sqlite` folder and select *Properties* and then the *Security* tab as in screen shot below. In most localhost cases, the ASP.Net identity is IIS_IUSRS which is highlighted below. Make sure that this user has full control over the sqlite folder.

[image]